# Get the number from the cell with the content 15days in excel when the value is already a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, text, numbers, formula

[image]

leadTimeD is the value i would like to get as a plain number without the text. This should be done in either a formula or a cell formatting way otherwise i have to repeat it for a lot of excel files.

i know the LEFT formula but as there is sometimes 5days and then 15days that wouldn't work without a very complicated formula to proof. is there really no simple way of just removing text or a specific text without any extra add-in whatsoever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP("Lead time (days)",purchasing!A1:C14,2,FALSE),"days",""),"day","")
```

Comment: I had to change it to =SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP("Lead time (days)",purchasing!A1:C14,2,FALSE),"days","") now it is working just fine thanks =)

Comment: @J.Doe sorry misunderstood the question, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, say you had 12A in cell A12, it returns 12. Array formula so use Ctrl + Shift and Enter. Wrap it in an IFERROR to handle no alpha character being present e.g. if was simply 12.

```
={LEFT(A12,MATCH(TRUE,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A12,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A12))),1))),0)-1)}
```

Example

[image: Insheet]

Comment: I took your formula and changed the reverence to G2 but it gave me only an error :(

Comment: Did you do ctrl , shift and enter to enter the formula? It does work.

Comment: yes i did press shift and enter to enter de formula, i don't know where i made the mistake. Unfortunately i can't post a picture here in the comment but there was an error message stating that im trying to do 1=1 and i should use a ' before the =

Comment: what is it saying? Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: Other thing to note is whether you need to use Trim(A12) to get rid of white space

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell format in column G to `[=1]0\d\a\y_);0\d\a\y\s;@` then retype in *15, 10, 30,* etc into the cells. Once that's done treat all lookups as a true number.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't changing anything or i don't get it right